# Where is the full screen state of a window saved in MacOSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

For testing purposes I would like to specify if my application should start with its main window in full screen mode or not.  MacOSX must persist this state somewhere since it restores the previous state, but I can't figure out where.

I would have guessed that this state would be stored in the defaults database for my application, since that's where window size and position is saved, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info about the saved state is in `~/Library/Saved Application State/<your app ID>.savedState`

Comment: Great! Found the full screen state in there. (Accepting soon.)